# Review, should we edit out apologies for bad English

Tags: discussion, english

One of the edits in my review queue correctly fixed a number of minor English errors.  The original author also apologizes for his bad English.

The apology looks out of place after the edit, should the editor in such a case also remove the apology?

Comment: It's noise, just like *"thanks in advance"* or *"my name is ..."*. After the language has been fixed it's also redundant noise. Feel free to click the improve edit button and get rid of it.

Comment: @ivarni , I tend to agree.  The review unfortunately was lost in the seven seas of Chrome tabs. Next time, I guess.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A post doesn't need apologies for bad English (but assume no bad intent), and we can see that for ourselves.

An editor should remove that kind of noise while they are improving the bad English to better English.

When you come across a suggested edit review that is worth keeping, but the editor left some noise (salutations, thanks, I'm new here, First time I use this code, bad at English, please don't down vote me, etc.), click *Improve Edit* to clean-up.

If the edit is not substantial (so a lot of noise got missed), reject the suggested edit.  I leave it up to the reviewer if they make the correct edit instead or leave that for others.

Comment: Tbh, if someone writes "_apologiez for bad Engrish_", it is done with good intend. However it does cause harm because writing that just makes it more obvious. This has been researched multiple times in psychology and is often referred as "_self-handicapping_".

Comment: *tongue firmly in cheek*,  I live in Japan, and what you refer to as "self-handicapping", here is just referred to as social protocol.

Comment: @visibleman I am aware of that, yet I am not sorry because I am not a Canadian. 

Comment: @rene It is a comment on yours first line in the answer, giving away a plausible reason why a user has added apologies in their post.

Comment: @KarelG, well I bet the Canadians are already sorry for whatever they did to have given the world cause for such sweeping generalization and prejudice.  ;-)